# How can 2 different UTF-8 encoded data generate the same Unicode string?

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8

I have very little knowledge about this, and would like to ask for help. The language I'm using is C#.

I have 2 words which are encoded to a UTF-8 CSV file:

1. `TĂ´̀‰ng`
2. `Tá»•ng`

I created a test Windows Form with 2 text boxes, and added the following event:

```
private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] decodeutf = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(textBox3.Text);


        textBox4.Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodeutf);
    }
```

Either 1 or 2 is input to `textBox3`.  I get the same result in `textBox4` as `Tổng`.

When I try to revert the same process to input `Tổng` to get result of 2, I always get 1 instead.

The revert code is as following (with another 2 text boxes):

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Encoding utf8 = new UTF8Encoding();
        byte[] encodedBytes = utf8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);

        textBox2.Text = Encoding.Default.GetString(encodedBytes);
    }
```

The result is only `TĂ´̀‰ng`.

What is the different between encoding to UTF-8 and reading back to Unicode as above?

Comment: http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/  Consider String.Normalize().

Comment: thank you very much @Hans Passant, String.Normalize() solved my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Encoding.Default` is [Windows-1258](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1258) (Vietnamese).

`'TĂ´̀‰ng'` encoded with Windows-1258, then decoded with UTF-8 generates the following five Unicode codepoints:

```
LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH CIRCUMFLEX
COMBINING HOOK ABOVE
LATIN SMALL LETTER N
LATIN SMALL LETTER G
```

`'Tá»•ng'` encoded as Windows-1258 and decoded as UTF-8 generates *four* Unicode codepoints:

```
LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH CIRCUMFLEX AND HOOK ABOVE
LATIN SMALL LETTER N
LATIN SMALL LETTER G
```

The difference is the first is a denormalized form using two codepoints for `ổ`.  The second uses a single codepoint for the combined character (normalized form).   They are visually the same.

Here's a third one, `'Tò‚̀‰ng'`, that becomes *six* Unicode characters after the encode/decode used above:

```
LATIN CAPITAL LETTER T
LATIN SMALL LETTER O
COMBINING CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT
COMBINING HOOK ABOVE
LATIN SMALL LETTER N
LATIN SMALL LETTER G
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Mark. This is very helpful and interesting knowledge. I'm able to generate the normalized Unicode point